# Confusion in choosing delay between Iterations

Tags: jmeter

My goal is to give exact 5000 milliseconds delay between Iterations.
Below are 2 approaches I have followed.

**Approach #:1** :ThreadGroup>Add TestAction>Add JSR223 Timer (see the below screenshot).

I am very clear on approach #1 and i can see the below lines in the jmeter.log(5000-Prev gettime)from this  i got confirmation delay between Iterations working.

2017-08-21 16:23:08,260 INFO o.a.j.t.JSR223Timer: 4831

2017-08-21 16:42:37,871 INFO o.a.j.t.JSR223Timer: 4835

**Approach #:2** : ThreadGroup>Add TestAction (see the below screenshot).

After I executed the test in the jmeter.log, i couldn't find any number indicating delay between Iterations.

**My Questions:**
1.For the 5000 milliseconds  delay between the iterations which approach should i follow Approach #:1 or Approach # 2.
2.If i use Approach #:2 as is how can and where can i cross check 5000 milliseconds are applying for each Iterations.
3.Is Approach #:2 correct i mean to say am i missing anything?

Please advise me! I am soo confused.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your Approach #1 is flaky as

   - Delay between requests will always be less than 5 seconds
   - Assuming this JSR223 Timer position the delay is applied to **all samplers**, if you want all threads to sleep for 5 seconds at the iteration start you need to add it **as a child of the first sampler**. References:

     - [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
     - [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)
2. Your Approach #2 is fine.

Where do you expect to see evidences of the delays? JMeter log won't contain any lines indicating the sleep happened and .jtl results file will neither show Test Action sampler result(s) nor JSR223 Timer (unless you put your sampler under a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) in "parent sample" mode configured to store duration of pre/post processors and timers).

The only way to see the "sleep" works is running your test 2 times: with and without "sleeps" (better with 1 virtual user), the total duration of the test with "sleeps" enabled should be 5 seconds longer.

Comment: Thanks  Dmitri for the clarification!I will go with approach #2. I Donot want 5000ms delay b/w each request.I am using constant timer for particular requests as child where ever it needed .I want 5000ms delay b/w Iterations.-Raj